# How to load user data using codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter-3

When I use different user account, it still load the same data from database. I want to display only the data of the specific user. How can I load the data of specific user? Thank you for your response.

Here is my view using ajax query.

```
     //loading the content
     $(document).ready(function(){
     {
     $.ajax({
      url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>kpi/loaddatatest",
      dataType:"JSON",
      method:"post",
      success:function(data){
     //Table will create when the ## ##     
        var html = '<tr>';  
        html += '<td id="kpi_description" contenteditable placeholder="Enter your KPI"></td>';
        html += '<td id="kra_description" contenteditable placeholder="Enter your KRA"></td>';
        html += '<td id="kpi_weight" contenteditable></td>';
        html += '<td></td>';
        html += '<td></td>';
        html += '<td><button type="button" name="btn_add" id="btn_add" class="btn btn-xs btn- 
         success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">+</span></button></td></tr>';
        for(var count = 0; count < data.length; count++)    
        {
        
          html += '<tr>';
          html += '<td class="table_data" data-row_id="'+data[count].id+'" data- 
           column_name="kpi_description" contenteditable>'+data[count].kpi_description+'</td>';
          html += '<td class="table_data" data-row_id="'+data[count].id+'" data- 
              column_name="kra_description" contenteditable>'+data[count].kra_description+'</td>';
          html += '<td class="table_data" data-row_id="'+data[count].id+'" data- 
           column_name="kpi_weight" disabled>'+data[count].kpi_weight+'</td>';
          html += '<td></td>';
          html += '<td></td>';
          html += '<td><button type="button" name="delete_btn" id="'+data[count].id+'" class="btn 
         btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">x</span></button> 
          </td></tr>';
        }
        $('#testtable').html(html);
        
       }
      });
     }
```

Here is my controller:

```
    public function loaddatatest()
    {
         
        $data = $this->Kpi_model->loaddatatest();
        
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

Here is my model:

```
   public function loaddatatest()
    {
    
        $this->db->order_by('id', 'ASCE');
        $data = $this->db->get('kpi_result'); 


        if($data->num_rows()>0)
            {

                return $data->result();
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Your model needs to have a where clause for the user. Something like `->where('user_id', $user_id)`

Comment: should I put user_id in the controller?

Comment: That depends on multiple factors. How is the user data stored / accessed? Are you using `$this->session->userdata('userdata');`? What is the database structure? Generally speaking you need to be limiting the query to the users data. As it is currently, the same data will be returned for all users.

Comment: I have employee_id in my database. and my table name in the database is 
kpi_result. controller: 

 public function loaddatatest() {
  $data = $this->Kpi_model->loaddatatest($user_id); 
  echo json_encode($data); } 
model:
   public function loaddatatest() {
   $this->db->order_by('id', 'ASC'); $data = $this->db->get_where('kpi_result', 
   ['employee_id' => $user_id])->result_array();
} 
I tried these code but not working. No data display

Comment: As you said `$data = $this->db->get_where('kpi_result', ['employee_id' => $user_id])->result_array();`, you're getting empty response, its mean that `$user_id` is not assigned.
Just use this line to get the query, `die($this->db->last_query());` and run it in `PhpMyAdmin`. Press `F12` and open `Network` tab to see the response of calling api.

Answer (score 0):

To query specific user make sure your database has id_user, when query can be done like this in loaddatatest()function using get_where().

```
$this->db->get_where('user_id', array('user_id => $user_id))
```

And you can pass specific user id through loaddatatest() argument like this

```
$data = $this->Kpi_model->loaddatatest($user_id);
```

Comment: I have employee_id in my database. and my table name in the database is 
kpi_result. controller: 

 public function loaddatatest() {
  $data = $this->Kpi_model->loaddatatest($user_id); 
  echo json_encode($data); } 
model:
   public function loaddatatest() {
   $this->db->order_by('id', 'ASC'); $data = $this->db->get_where('kpi_result', 
   ['employee_id' => $user_id])->result_array();
} 
I tried these code but not working. No data display